# replace number after underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I nee to replace all numbers after underline inside a string.

I think that I can use Regex, but I don't know how to use Regex Syntax

See an example of my string:

```
milton_0
milton_1
```

Comment: Replace them with what?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: replace with other number that I will generate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how specific or broad you want to be, but you can try this:

```
var starter = "milton_1";
var specialVal = "asdf";

var re = /^(milton_)(\d+)$/;

var replaced = starter.replace(re, function (match, p1) {
    return p1 + specialVal;
});

console.log(replaced);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ne4cD/

This will match a string starting with "milton_" and ending with digits. It replaces any digits after the "_" with the `specialVal` value.

An example of simply incrementing that number is:

```
var starter = "milton_1";
var re = /^(milton_)(\d+)$/;

var replaced = starter.replace(re, function (match, p1, p2) {
    return p1 + (+p2 + 1);
});

console.log(replaced);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ne4cD/2/

**UPDATE:**

If the "milton" part isn't static, then you're really only targeting the "_" with digits after it. So something like this:

```
var starter = "asdfkjlasdfjksadf_1";
var specialVal = "asdf";

var re = /(_)(\d+)/g;

var replaced = starter.replace(re, function (match, p1) {
    return p1 + specialVal;
});

console.log(replaced);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ne4cD/3/

And maybe a little better to see: http://jsfiddle.net/ne4cD/4/

Comment: and If I dont know whats the text before underscore?

Comment: @tomcamara Just edited my answer. Let me know if that helps or if you need more info

Answer (score 4):

If that is the standard format, You can use `split()`

```
var str = 'milton_1';
alert(str.split('_')[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. The following code in enough

```
var str = "milton_0";
str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("_"));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need them as list for handling easily.

```
var listOfStrings = yourStringObject('whateverYourCharacterUnderEachWord').ToList<string>();
```

After that you need to get rid of number for each string in the list and add what you want.

```
foreach(string word in listOfStrings){
word = word.Substring(0,word.IndexOf('_')+1);
word = word + "characterThatYouWantToAddHere"
}
```